# Perché si utilizzano sia il congiuntivo che il futuro dell'indicativo dopo "finché" in questa frase?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Leggevo una ricetta e ho notato la seguente frase:

> Aggiustate di sale e cuocete ... finché i pomodorini saranno appassiti e la cicoria si insaporisca bene.

Da quello che capisco, sia il congiuntivo che il futuro dell'indicativo vengono usati dopo "finché" e la scelta del modo corrisponde a una leggera differenza di significato (la differenza comunque mi pare ben sottile e non pretendo di capirla perfettamente). Nella frase sopra riportata, un verbo all'indicativo è seguito direttamente da un verbo al congiuntivo, e in tutti e due casi il significato sembra essere sostanzialmente lo stesso.

Pensate che ci sia una ragione specifica per cui l'autrice l'ha scritta così?

Comment: Vedo solo una frase scritta malino: *finché i pomodorini appassiscano e la cicoria si insaporisca bene*.

Comment: Anche a me sembra una frase molto brutta. Penso in una situazione simile nelle mie lingue (catalano e spagnolo). Anche in queste lingue ci sono costrutti che ammettono sia l'indicativo sia il congiuntivo. Ma usare nella stessa  costruzione l'indicativo insieme al congiuntivo lo troverei una scelta molto brutta.

Answer (score -1):

Secondo quanto riporta la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/finche/), con la congiunzione *finché* si può utilizzare anche il congiuntivo (anche se questo utilizzo è più raro e letterario).

Secondo me il significato nei due casi è leggermente diverso: nella frase riportata è stata omessa una seconda congiunzione, ovvero *affinchè* (= allo scopo di), per cui la frase più completa sarebbe:

> Aggiustate di sale e cuocete ... finché i pomodorini saranno appassiti e **(affinché)** la cicoria si insaporisca bene.

Si potrebbe ipotizzare che questa omissione sia stata fatta per non appesantire la frase (finché/affinché suona come una ripetizione anche se non lo è).